# HIghcharts column tickmarks not aligned to column

Tags: highcharts

I have a column chart with 11 columns where I would like to have a tick mark with a label on the x-axis in the middle of each column. However, I can't get the tickmarks and labels to align with my columns. I have created a jsfiddle to illustrate my problem. I have set min, max and tickInterval on the x-axis but it doesn't seem to use the min and max value at all. Instead my start tick show 7.2 and the last 27. What am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/8218/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    "chart": {
        "width": 850,
        "height": 450,
    type: 'column'
    },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPlacement: 'between'
    }
  },
    "yAxis": [{
        "lineWidth": 1,
        "gridLineWidth": 1,
        "tickWidth": 1,
    }],
    "xAxis": [{
        "startOnTick": true,
        "endOnTick": true,
        "min": 8,
        "max": 26,
        "tickInterval": 1.8,
        "gridLineWidth": 1,
        "tickWidth": 1,
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
    }],
    "series": [{
        "data": [
            [8, 4.15],
            [9.8, 17.61],
            [11.6, 48.32],
            [13.4, 108.65],
            [15.2, 53.92],
            [17, 138.87],
            [18.8, 152.77],
            [20.6, 69.17],
            [22.4, 18.27],
            [24.2, 8.82],
            [26, 1.43]
        ],
        "name": "Test",
    "pointStart": 8,
    "pointInterval": 1.8
    }]
});
```

Comment: It does! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tickPositions` you can put ticks wherever you may want them. So for example to fit with your columns, you can do:

```
xAxis: [{
  tickPositions: [8, 9.8, 11.6, 13.4...]
  ...
}]
```

**Working example**: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/LLExL/8219/

**API on xAxis.tickPositions:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions